# How do you connect to a mail server from a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, imap, smtpclient

I am trying to send and receive mail of known structure from a GMail account without user intervention.

Is there an elegant way to make IMAP and SMTP connections from a Firefox extension without overcomplicating things by involving [C++](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_Custom_Firefox_Extensions_with_the_Mozilla_Build_System) or [Python](http://code.google.com/p/pythonext/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [nsISocketTransportService.createTransport()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISocketTransportService#createTransport%28%29) to open a connection, something like this:

```js
var Cc = Components.classes;
var Ci = Components.interfaces;

var socket = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/socket-transport-service;1"]
               .getService(Ci.nsISocketTransportService)
               .createTransport(["ssl"], 1, "pop.gmail.com", 995, null);

var input = socket.openInputStream(Ci.nsITransport.OPEN_UNBUFFERED, 0, 0);
var scriptableInput = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
                        .createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableInputStream);
scriptableInput.init(input);


var output = socket.openOutputStream(Ci.nsITransport.OPEN_UNBUFFERED, 0, 0);
```

This gets you an input and output stream. You can receive data via [`nsIScriptableInputStream.read()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIScriptableInputStream#read%28%29) and send it via [`nsIOutputStream.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIOutputStream#write%28%29). But you would still have to implement IMAP/SMTP logic yourself (you cannot use the current implementation in Thunderbird at it is written in C++ and the new JavaScript-based implementation isn't ready yet).

Comment: Hi Wladimir, can you tell me whether it is possible to do a normal Ajax query from a Firefox extension. Say for a webpage from a website foo.com, when the Ajax url is specified as `test.php`, the request goes to `foo.com/test.php`, which can send appropriate results. How do I do it in a Firefox extension, given there is no website where it belongs, per se? Do I have to do it through JSONP?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: How about creating a new question rather than asking in a comment on an entirely unrelated question? Or just searching, there are tons of existing questions about that.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733573 is about implementing a TCP API for web applications; this is a work in progress and will likely be available only in Firefox 17 at best. However, if you read the patch (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=643432&action=diff#a/b2g/components/TCPSocket.js_sec1) the TCPSocket object exposes pretty much everything you need for making an SSL connection to an arbitrary server, so you should be able to steal this code!

Comment: The question is about extensions, not web applications. Extensions already have access to a sockets API and it isn't anything new.

Comment: Sure, but the patch contains a nice example of how to use the sockets api from chrome code, and the person who asked may be able to steal the abstraction there, since he asked for an elegant way.